# Trying to get property 'profile_picture' of non-object backend\students\contact.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am getting this error

```
Trying to get property 'profile_picture' of non-object (View: D:\projet7899\laravel-only-school-managemnt\resources\views\backend\students\contact.blade.php`)
```

In **contact.blade.php**

```
<img class="w-20 h-20 sm:w-32 sm:h-32 rounded" src="{{ asset('images/profile/' .$student->user->profile_picture) }}" alt="avatar">
```

In the **StudentController.php**
I have this function

```
 public function contact(Student $student) {
     $class = Grade::with('subjects')->where('id', $student->class_id)->first();

     return view('backend.students.contact', compact('class','student'));
}
```

It is the same structure of other function named a show that is working properly but this one is not well working I just need to get the value of the email of the user
I don't know if it is legitimate to share the whole GitHub link code
. Thanks in advance

Comment: do a `dd($student->user)` in your controller, you will have the answer

Comment: Yes it is returning null but I did not understand it is not like show  which is working and returning value

Comment: @askermad789.can you route as well

Comment: Add to your question the code of the relation `user()` in Student::class but you better also verify your database data, maybe some of the student dont have User attached to them.

Comment: public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because you are trying to access `profile_picture` on the `user` model when the user model doesn't actually exist.

What you need to do is in your view check to make sure the user model actually exists

```
<img class="w-20 h-20 sm:w-32 sm:h-32 rounded" src="{{ !empty($student->user) ? asset('images/profile/' .$student->user->profile_picture) : asset('link to a generic image') }}" alt="avatar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Access profile_picture from the student object

```html
<img class="w-20 h-20 sm:w-32 sm:h-32 rounded"
                                 src="{{ asset('images/profile/' .$student->profile_picture) }}" alt="avatar">
```